# How to Configure Eclipse build bath for multiple OS

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse for linux i setted up the run/configuration path like this
[image]

and it is working fine, but this project should also run on windows, and the problem, in windows is
that the `/` is inverted with `\`, and those gives problem.
Is there a way to configure that it makes this symbol based on the OS?
or any way to avoid this problem

Comment: Java supports `/` on Windows. Just use `/` instead of ``\``.

Comment: thank you, i didnt know

Comment: Don't use VM arguments for this. Instead, add the JARs in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_ tab libraries to the _Modulepath_. Otherwise, in your launch configurations you will get a command line with two conflicting modulepaths arguments (Eclipse use the short argument `-p` for that: hit the _Show Command Line_ button in your launch configuration to see what command line is generated).